# Git push origin master timed out

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to put my project on github. I can't understand why I'm getting this error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I do this:

```
git push origin master
```

I've been following these instructions exactly, generated by github:

```
Next steps:
  mkdir UniqCheck
  cd UniqCheck
  git init
  touch README
  git add README
  git commit -m 'first commit'
  git remote add origin git@github.com:dylandrop/UniqCheck.git
  git push -u origin master
```

I don't know why I'm getting the error. I've been successfully pushing and pulling from a different git repo (not owned by me) for another project. None of the other questions I've seen have worked so far, or have matched my problem exactly.

Edit:
Also, maybe of interest, this is what I get when I do a git config --get-regexp '^(remote|branch).'

```
remote.origin.url git@github.com:dylandrop/UniqCheck.git
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Have you checked out your SSH keys already?

Comment: @mschonaker Not sure what you mean... But I was concerned that I wasn't being asked for my SSH password like I usually am when I push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working now. I'm guessing I just decided to push too quickly, and github hadn't processed my project yet. Weird.